# Non-numeric quantities used as arguments in R Function

Tags: r, function

In a `function()` I'm writing, I'm wondering **how to allow** **one of the arguments** of the function to be entered **as non-numeric characters** (i.e., words) but then I will be translating those non-numeric characters back to numeric values?

I'm using the **following simple R code (with no success):**

```
a = medium

if(a == "medium"){a = 1/2}else 
  if(a == "wide"){a = sqrt(2)/2}else
    if(a == "verywide"){a = 1}
```

Comment: ... and `else` and `if` should be on the same line

Comment: Alternatively: `a = c(medium = 1/2, wide = sqrt(2)/2, verywide = 1)[a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `a = medium`, `R` will look for an object named `medium` and not character `"medium"`. Note that `"` is only for displaying. Actual character is `medium` (Run `cat("medium")` to check)

You're code can be fixed as below:

```
a = "medium"

if(a == "medium"){
    a = 1/2
} else if (a == "wide"){
    a = sqrt(2)/2
} else if (a == "verywide"){
    a = 1
}
```

Comment: You can avoid typing `a =` three times by assigning the entire statement `a = if ...`

Comment: Darshan, is there a way that user simply puts `medium` instead of `"medium"`? That is, the user write `a = medium` instead of `"a = medium"`?